# PRML: Why the elements of y(x) sums to 1? (Chapter 4.1.3)

Tags: least-squares, linear-algebra

I could not understand the reason why PRML ([Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Christopher Michael Bishop](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387310732)) says:

> An interesting property of least-squares solutions with multiple target variables
>   is that if every target vector in the training set satisfies some linear constraint
>   $$ a^\top t_n+b=0 \tag{4.18} $$
>   for some constants a and b, then the model prediction for any value of x will satisfy the same constraint so that
>   $$ a^\top y(x)+b=0. \tag{4.19} $$
>   Thus if we use a 1-of-K coding scheme for K classes, then the predictions made
>   by the model will have the property that the elements of y(x) will sum to 1 for any
>   value of x.

Why?
If the element of $y(x)$ sum to 1, it should be that $\mathbb{a} = \mathbb{1}$ and $b=-1$.

Comment: although PRML book is famous, it is still nice to use the full name and provide the Amazon book link for more people to understand your question.

Comment: Some additional context for the formula would be helpful... What does it describe? What does the book say about it?

Comment: @Tim thank you. I put the quote from the book, with some context.

Comment: Are you asking what a 1-of-K coding scheme is?  Or are you asking about vector notation?

Comment: @whuber no, I am asking why the elements of y(x) sums to 1. I understand that 1) 1-of-K coding, 2) vector notation, and 3) the elements of t_n sums to 1.

Comment: In 1-of-K coding, by definition, the elements of the vectors always sum to unity (because one component is $1$ and all the others are $0$). From the assertion that predictions satisfy the same constraint it seems like one can easily and immediately deduce the result you ask about.  Thus, there doesn't seem to be a real question here--at least nothing that hasn't already been answered directly in your post.  Could you clarify?

Comment: @whuber thank you. Now I could understand. Because $t_n$ is one-hot, it holds $a^\top t_n + b = 0$ --> every element of $a$ is $-b$. Then $a^\top y(x) + b = -b(1^\top y(x) - 1) = 0$, means the sum of elements of $y(x)$ is 1. (trivial solution $b = 0$ was ignored)